# postgressql/typeorm - Count with filter on same table and join with another

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, count, typeorm

I am working with PostgresSQL as DBMS and typeorm as ORM
I need write a query a little bit complicated for me.
The database structure that looks like this:

```
Results
| PersonId | Result   |
|----------|----------|
| 1        | Rejected |
| 1        | Rejected |
| 1        | Passed   |
| 1        | Passed   |
| 2        | Rejected |
| 2        | Passed   |
| 3        | Rejected |
| 3        | Rejected |
| 3        | Rejected |
| 3        | Rejected |
| 3        | Passed   |

OtherTable
| PersonId | OtherColumn |
|----------|-------------|
| 1        | ...         |
| 1        | ...         |
| 1        | ...         |
| 2        | ...         |
| 2        | ...         |
| 3        | ...         |
| 3        | ...         |
| 3        | ...         |
| 3        | ...         |
```

How do I get for each person id the number of times they got rejected and passed? And is it possibile in the same query to the number of times they appear in another query?

```
| PersonId | Rejected | Passed | CountFromOtherTable
|----------|----------|--------| -----------------
| 1        | 2        | 2      | 3
| 2        | 1        | 1      | 2
| 3        | 4        | 1      | 3
```

Just the SQL query is also good, with that I can try to translate it to use with typeorm.

Comment: What if the two tables have different people?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you want conditional aggregation.  In Postgres, I would recommend using `filter` and `left join` for this:

```
select r.PersonId,
       count(*) filter (where r.result = 'Rejected') as Rejected,
       count(*) filter (where r.result = 'Passed') as Passed
       coalesce(o.cnt, 0) as other_table_cnt
from Results r left join
     (select personid, count(*) as cnt
      from othertable o
      group by personid
     ) o
     using (personid)
group by r.PersonId;
```

Note:  This assumes that you want all persons in the first table, hence the `left join`.  If you want all persons in *both* tables, then use `inner join`.  If you want all persons in *either* table, use `full join`.

Answer (score 0):

By using conditional aggregation with group by you can get Rejected and Passed column and for CountFromOtherTable you can use subquery.

```
select PersonId, sum (case when result='Rejected' then 1 else 0 end) Rejected ,
sum (case when result='Passed' then 1 else 0 end) Passed ,
(select count(*) from othertable o where o.personid=r.personid)CountFromOtherTable
from Results r
group by PersonId
```

DB-Fiddle:

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table Results ( PersonId int, Result   varchar(50));
 insert into Results values( 1,        'Rejected');
 insert into Results values( 1,        'Rejected');
 insert into Results values( 1,        'Passed');
 insert into Results values( 1,        'Passed');
 insert into Results values( 2,        'Rejected');
 insert into Results values( 2,        'Passed');
 insert into Results values( 3,        'Rejected');
 insert into Results values( 3,        'Rejected');
 insert into Results values( 3,        'Rejected');
 insert into Results values( 3,        'Rejected');
 insert into Results values( 3,        'Passed');
 
 create table OtherTable (PersonId int);
 insert into OtherTable values( 1 );
 insert into OtherTable values( 1 );
 insert into OtherTable values( 1 );
 insert into OtherTable values( 2 );
 insert into OtherTable values( 2 );
 insert into OtherTable values( 3 );
 insert into OtherTable values( 3 );
 insert into OtherTable values( 3 );
 insert into OtherTable values( 3 );
```

Query:

```
 select PersonId, sum (case when result='Rejected' then 1 else 0 end) Rejected ,
 sum (case when result='Passed' then 1 else 0 end) Passed ,
 (select count(*) from othertable o where o.personid=r.personid)CountFromOtherTable
 from Results r
 group by PersonId
 order by PersonId
```

Output:

| personid | rejected | passed | countfromothertable |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 | 1 | 4 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=bf1f7c206f4cd20a78897762efa2eaff)*